# Can't install Tensorflow.Keras : unable to resolve 'PureHDF'

Tags: visual-studio, tensorflow, keras, nuget

I'm trying to follow [this simple getting started guide](https://scisharp.github.io/tensorflow-net-docs/#/essentials/introduction) for tensorflow.net and am already blocked at the first lines.

I installed TensorFlow.Net, TensorFlow.Keras and SciSharp.TensorFlow.Redist-Windows-GPU as discribed [here](https://scisharp.github.io/tensorflow-net-docs/#/essentials/installation)

The code starts with

```
using static Tensorflow.Binding;
using static Tensorflow.KerasApi;
using Tensorflow;
using Tensorflow.NumPy;
```

EDIT: I didn't see that Tensorflow.keras didn't install because of an error:

```
Unable to resolve dependency 'PureHDF'. Source(s) used: 'nuget.org', 'Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages'.
```

In fact I can install Tensorflow.keras in a blank project, but here it's in a unity project. But I don't see wyh a nuget package shouldn't be found here and not there.

Comment: I'm not seeing this when I tried https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uwl1p.png It does say "Tensorflow.KerasApi is Deprecated" but otherwise it works.  Check the installed nugets (I included what I have installed in my screenshot)

Comment: I edited the question because in fact this is because of TF.keras not installing

Comment: I am the developer of the dependency not being resolved properly (PureHDF). My guess ist that because PureHDF is still an alpha release, it is not being detected by Unity. At least in Visual Studio you have to enable the "include prereleases" checkbox to include these in your search results. I am actively working on a final release, though, so that should not be an issue anymore soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the csproj settings on my side:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="SciSharp.TensorFlow.Redist" Version="2.11.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="SciSharp.TensorFlow.Redist-Windows-GPU" Version="2.10.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="TensorFlow.Keras" Version="0.10.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="TensorFlow.NET" Version="0.100.4" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

And above dependencies work fine:

[image]

I think the KeraApi should comes from TensorFlow.NET package, and the issue should comes from packages incompatible or dependencies was not been totally loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same problem. Install PureHDF ("Install-Package PureHDF -Version 1.0.0-alpha.25"), apparently due to the fact that this is an alpha version, you can only install it if you specify the exact version. After that TensorFlow.Keras installs fine